# application crashing with - dyld: Symbol not found: _NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6

i am using xcode 6 . application runs successfully on simulator but when i am using my device than after building the application it is crashed and sending this report. this code was running with xcode 5.

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/7BA2B5A2-E764-46F6-A012-8FB94BCD1C4C/FutureAPI.app/FutureAPI
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
 in /var/mobile/Applications/7BA2B5A2-E764-46F6-A012-8FB94BCD1C4C/FutureAPI.app/FutureAPI
```

Answer (score 0):

answer is https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2109. i have just deleted CFNetwork.framework and my code is running.